# Check if values do not exist in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this very simple goal but I couldn't think of any simple solution. I have a list of values which will come from user input and I want to check if at least one of them does not exist in the database. Note that entered values can have duplicates.

myTable:

```
| id | name |
| 0  | Bob  |
| 1  | Ben  |
| 2  | John |
| 3  | Rex  |
```

Sample values entered by a user:

1, 2, 2, 4

Count of values that do not exist, in this case, the 4 so:

1

I could do something like this:

```
select count(userInput.value)
from
   (select 1 as value
    union all
    select 2
    union all
    select 2
    union all
    select 4) as userInput
left join myTable
on myTable.value = myTable.id
where myTable.id is null
```

The code above will count all values without match (myTable.id is null) from myTable. This will work but I'm looking for a simple solution that does not require the use of many union. Anybody who have tried doing that?

**EDIT**

This does not work!

```
select count(myTable.id)
from myTable
where myTable.id not in(1,2,2,4)
```

The code above will count IDs that do not exist in the input values which will result to 2 since IDs 0 and 3 do not exist in the input values. Note that the expected output is 1  since the value 4 is the only one that does not exist in the table.

Comment: Why not use `NOT IN`?

Comment: Because it will return rows from MyTable which do not exist in the input values. It will NOT return values which do not exist in MyTable.

Comment: I want to check whether the input values do not exist in MyTable, not the other way around.

Comment: @dbp - How are you building your query? What tools are at your disposal?

Comment: On a separate topic, you may want to add your version of SQL Server to your tags.

Comment: @PM77-1 I use VB.NET to construct my query and my database server is 2005.

Comment: @dpp I've proposed two methods for evaulating the values; one to check whether they exist, the other whether they do not exist. I'm still not understanding why neither one will work.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk and I still don't understand why your proposed solution will work. Maybe if you post your answer I could try using it.

Comment: @dpp - Do you need an accurate count (like your query will produce) or  do you "want to check if at least one of them does not exist in the database" (like you put in your post)?

Comment: Re-read your question. I think the approach you have will work best.

Comment: @PM77-1 yes, I want to know if at least one does not exist.

Comment: If you don't want to build the unions, perhaps you should store the user input values into a temporary table and join against that. Same effect, but without the ugly unions.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk I'm not sure if the code I added is what you were trying to propose but it really is not working.

Comment: I will have to concede that you do need to combine user inputs into a query result or temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  (SELECT 1 value
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 4) ui
LEFT JOIN myTable mt
  ON mt.id = ui.value
```

Returns

```
| VALUE |     ID |   NAME |
---------------------------
|     1 |      1 |    Ben |
|     2 |      2 |   John |
|     2 |      2 |   John |
|     4 | (null) | (null) |
```

So, ask the count where `id` `IS NULL`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
FROM
  (SELECT 1 value
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 4) ui
LEFT JOIN myTable mt
  ON mt.id = ui.value
WHERE mt.id IS NULL
```

**Result**

```
| CNT |
-------
|   1 |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b868c/1)

Comment: Yes it will work but I was just wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing it. The unions doesn't look nice. :/

Comment: @dpp Apologies for misreading your question. It may not be elegant but it's the most efficient in my opinion. It's not efficient to send `n` requests for `n` user values.

Comment: Its okay. Thanks! I guess I can't avoid using union or temporary table.

Comment: @dpp You can use a table variable instead of a temporary table. It only exists in the scope of the current query. Bottom line, the user input needs to be in once place, however it gets there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in front of my Pc but something like:

```
Select id from mytable where (
Select count(id) 
From myTable
where id in (1,2,4) 
Group by id) =0
```

Might work